# How to migrate Java, Hadoop on-premise applications to Azure

Tags: azure, migration, azure-hdinsight

How to migrate Java, Hadoop on-premise applications to Azure?

Please advise me the architecture and steps to follow. How to discover, group and start migration.

Comment: @nodakai this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

Before migrating to Azure, try to [Understand the difference between Azure HDInsight and on-premise Hadoop cluster](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/how-to-choose-the-right-hdinsight-cluster).

Before deploying an HDInsight cluster, plan for the desired cluster capacity by determining the needed performance and scale. This planning helps optimize both usability and costs. Some cluster capacity decisions cannot be changed after deployment. If the performance parameters change, a cluster can be dismantled and re-created without losing stored data.

The key questions to ask for capacity planning are:

- In which geographic region should you deploy your cluster?
- How much storage do you need?
- What cluster type should you deploy?
- What size and type of virtual machine (VM) should your cluster nodes use?
- How many worker nodes should your cluster have?

Each and every question is addressed here: "[Capacity planning for HDInsight Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-capacity-planning)".